# simplejson build hang

Tags: python, setuptools

On windows 7 32-bit I'm having trouble getting simplejson installed. I have fresh installs of Python 2.7.1 and setuptools 0.6c11. `easy_install -v simplejson` stalls when building ._speedups.

```
Running simplejson-2.1.6\setup.py bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\user\appdata\
local\temp\easy_install-jwfwpp\simplejson-2.1.6\egg-dist-tmp-0zkmua
Importing new compiler from distutils.msvc9compiler
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing simplejson.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to simplejson.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to simplejson.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'simplejson.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'simplejson.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-2.7
creating build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson
copying simplejson\decoder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson
copying simplejson\encoder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson
copying simplejson\ordered_dict.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson
copying simplejson\scanner.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson
copying simplejson\tool.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson
copying simplejson\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson
creating build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_check_circular.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejso
n\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_decimal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests

copying simplejson\tests\test_decode.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_default.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests

copying simplejson\tests\test_dump.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_encode_basestring_ascii.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\
simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_encode_for_html.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejs
on\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_fail.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_float.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_indent.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_pass1.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_pass2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_pass3.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
copying simplejson\tests\test_recursion.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tes
ts
copying simplejson\tests\test_scanstring.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\te
sts
copying simplejson\tests\test_separators.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\te
sts
copying simplejson\tests\test_speedups.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\test
s
copying simplejson\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests

copying simplejson\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\simplejson\tests
running build_ext
building 'simplejson._speedups' extension
```

There is a cmd.exe churning at about 15% cpu usage indefinitely. I've let it run for ~30 minutes. I've only seen this behavior on a single machine, but what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that installing simplejson on 2.7 is not usefull as it is available as json module in stdlib

Comment: Oh. That's nice. Happy to take that step out of my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install visual studio to a non-standard location. setuptools can't seem to find it. easy_install ended up being happy with MSVC either removed (in which case no speedups were compiled) or in the default installation path.